# Can not loop through FOR XML AUTO results

Tags: sql-server, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am taking some data from DB through stored procedure and i am using FOR XML AUTO to get this data.
query is like this

```
WHERE ITEMNUMBER=@itemid AND DATASET = @dataset FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS) AS filters
```

and result xml is

```
    <filters extra="filters">
    <ISP_WebItem>
      <FILTER>Type</FILTER>
      <FILTERNAME>Matematik</FILTERNAME>
      <UNITCODE></UNITCODE>
    </ISP_WebItem>
    <ISP_WebItem>
      <FILTER>Strømkilde</FILTER>
      <FILTERNAME>Solceller</FILTERNAME>
      <UNITCODE></UNITCODE>
    </ISP_WebItem>
  </filters>
```

Now my problem is that when i try to loop through this result in my xslt,I am unable to get any result.
My XSLT code is like this

```
  <xsl:variable name="filt" select="msxsl:node-set(filters)"/>   
<xsl:for-each select="$filt/ISP_WebItem">   
  <xsl:copy-of select="FILTER"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am getting the filter xml correctly in my 'filt' variable, but the for each loop never executes correctly.
When i tried putting break points in my code,I noticed that code execution never enters inside the loop ,that means

```
 <xsl:for-each select="filt/ISP_WebItem">
```

this piece of code never satisfies.
And for extra info this filter node is a part of large XML data,every other nodes in this data is working correctly(ie i can loop or do any operation with them).
can any one suggest any possible reasons.

Comment: How is it meant to magically know that `filt` in your select is a reference to a variable, and not meant to be interpreted as a regular part of an XPath query?

Comment: Can you show your expected output in this case, as well as the output you are currently getting? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC: I need to show each 'ISP_WebItem' node data in a grid listing.

Comment: Can you show the exact output you are getting when you do just `<xsl:copy-of select="$filt"/>`, as that might help solve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC the same i have given in my question

<filters extra="filters"><ISP_WebItem FILTER="Note" FILTERNAME="Med klemme" UNITCODE=""/><ISP_WebItem FILTER="Antal" FILTERNAME="25" UNITCODE="stk"/><ISP_WebItem FILTER="Længde" FILTERNAME="9" UNITCODE="cm"/><ISP_WebItem FILTER="Bredde" FILTERNAME="6" UNITCODE="cm"/></filters>

Comment: That is different to the XML in your question. In your question, the **FILTER** is an element. In your comment above, it is an attribute. I have amended by answer to expand it a bit though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your XSLT. Firstly, **filt** is a variable, and so you need to prefix it with a $ to indicate this, otherwise the XSLT will be looking for an element named **filt**

```
<xsl:for-each select="$filt/ISP_WebItem">
```

Secondly, in your XML sample, **FILTER** is an element, but your **xsl:copy-of** statement is looking for an attribute named 'FILTER'. You should be doing this

```
<xsl:copy-of select="FILTER"/>
```

However, if it is an attribute, leave it as `<xsl:copy-of select="@FILTER"/>`

This XSLT would work, for example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" extension-element-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="filt" select="msxsl:node-set(filters)"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$filt/ISP_WebItem">
         <xsl:copy-of select="FILTER"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In fact, if you did just want to copy the elements, and nothing else, you could remove the **xsl:for-each** and simplify it to this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" extension-element-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="filt" select="filters"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$filt/ISP_WebItem/FILTER"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I am not quite sure if you need to use **node-set** in this instance (although I guess you are just showing an abdriged code sample, so maybe it is necessary for something elsewhere).

The following would also work

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" extension-element-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="filters/ISP_WebItem">
         <xsl:copy-of select="FILTER"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:** If you are still getting problems, try one of the following expessions instead.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$filt//ISP_WebItem">
```

Comment: :I have changed the errors you have pointed thanks for that.but my problem is still on . I am getting correct results for 
  <xsl:copy-of select="$filt"/>
but for this 
  <xsl:copy-of select="$filt/ISP_WebItem"/>
nothing.
and i think this is the root cause of my for loop issue also